# Empty object instead of Map<string, string[]> sent via httpClient.post

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to send Map<string, string[]> as a field of DO sent via http.post(). Method that calls post looks like that: `this.http.post<Something>('/something', somethingDO);`
DO looks basically like that:

```
export interface Something {
a: boolean;
b: number;
c: Map<string, string[]>
}
```

if I set chrome devTools breakpoint on post's call I can see that c is filled with data and looks like that:

```
Map(1) {'first' => Array(5),}
```

`0:  {"first" => Array(5)} key: "first" value: Array(5) 0: "A7" 1: "A8" 2: "A9" 3: "A10" 4: "B1"`

but if I try to use JSON.stringify on this object it returns indeed simply {}. So it seems for me, that this map cannot be sent in this format, but my Java app expects exactly Map<String, List>. Is this a way to send this map?